# SOAP over HTTP and SOAP over JMS

Tags: web-services, http, soap, jms

I have a requirement where a web service has to be exposed both as SOAP over HTTP and JMS. How would be the bindings for both in a WSDL at the same time ?

Also what all extra care(compared to a simple web service SOAP over HTTP) need to be taken for generating and deploying webservice in this scenario?

If possible, please give an example of a WSDL where both bindings are mentioned.

Comment: You may have to create a wsdl one for each `http, jms`.